# How to find the number of value in range of integers in a column of a data frame in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So i have this big dataframe with alot of columns like age, name, sex, etc.

I want to make a new column with age group between 1-10, 11-20, 21-30,...,71-80

I tried to do

```
ranges = [1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
df.age.groupby(pd.cut(df.age, ranges)).count()
```

and the result is

```
age
(1, 10]      64
(10, 20]    162
(20, 30]    361
(30, 40]    210
(40, 50]    132
(50, 60]     62
(60, 70]     27
(70, 80]      6
Name: age, dtype: int64
```

which is exactly what i wanted but the groups are incorrect. i want it to be 1-10 and then 11-20 not 1-10 and 10-20. Can anybody help me solve this problem?

Comment: `(10, 20] ` means "between 10 and 20, excluding 10 and including 20" due to the parenthesis format.

Comment: `labels = [f'{x+1}-{y}' if x != 1 else f'{x}-{y}' for x, y in zip(ranges, ranges[1:])]` - pass this to the labels parameter of `pd.cut`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first is necessary explain by comment of @samthegolden:

> (10, 20] means "between 10 and 20, excluding 10 and including 20" due to the parenthesis format.

But you can do it by `labels` parameter created by `ranges` with `zip` in list comprehension:

```
np.random.seed(2020)
df = pd.DataFrame({'age':np.random.randint(1, 80, size=100)})

ranges = [1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
labels = ['{}-{}'.format(i + 1, j) for i, j in zip(ranges[:-1], ranges[1:])] 
labels[0] = '{}-{}'.format(ranges[0], ranges[1])
print (labels)
['1-10', '11-20', '21-30', '31-40', '41-50', '51-60', '61-70', '71-80']

ranges = [1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
s = df.age.groupby(pd.cut(df.age, ranges, labels=labels)).count()
print (s)

age
1-10     14
11-20    10
21-30    15
31-40    12
41-50     7
51-60    11
61-70    18
71-80    12
Name: age, dtype: int64
```